# How to pass list to POST parameter asp.net web request

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I have a web service that has list as parameter:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void getDepartmentBy(List<string> key, List<string> value)
    {
        string condition = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!value.Equals(""))
            {
                condition = condition + "[" + key + "]" + " = '" + value + "' and ";
            }
        }  

        Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(condition));
    }
```

I try to set the parameter like this:

```
string postString = string.Format("key={0}&value={1}", key, value);
```

But it's not working!
Is there a way to pass list to parameter web request?